# Plugin is not being found after I install it in local repo

Tags: maven, nexus

I have written a plugin and to install it in the local repository I run the command :

```
mvn install
```

The plugin is successfully added to my local maven repository but when I run :

```
com.tools:generate:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:generatepom
```

I receive the error :

> plugin com.tools:generate:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies
>   could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for
>   com.tools:generate:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find
>   com.tools:generate:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT in
>   https://nexus.mydomain.com:8181/prod/content/groups/level0/ was cached
>   in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the
>   update interval of nexuspro-level0 has elapsed or updates are forced
>   -> [Help 1]

It seems to be searching for the plugin on Nexus even though the plugin is installed locally. How can I configure maven to run the plugin in the local repository ?

Here is the build & beginning of pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>generate</artifactId>
    <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>generate</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <configuration>
                    <repositoryUri>http://repository.sonatype.org/service/local/lucene/search?sha1=</repositoryUri>                 
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 1):

most likely your plugin's pom contains different identification (groupId,artifactId,version).

Also, make sure that you specified maven-plugin there.

If it is not the case, please provide plugin's pom excerpt, or its build log excerpt (the "istalling ..." part).

You can read about developing plugins [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/index.html).

Comment: thanks, ive added more info to the question. when I changed the pom group and artifcat id's to match the plugin group and artifact id's I can run the plugin. So running the plugin uses the artifact and group id's of the pom itself, not the group and artifact id's of configured within the plugin section itself ?

Comment: uff this is not the way - the plugin project cannot use itself to build itself - which is what your pom.xml tries to do... Try building it with empty local repository, it cannot pass then. You need to remove the /project/build/plugins/plugin[artifactId='generate'] part completely; then `mvn install` and then `cd elsewhere` and try your invocation command

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to turn your approach around and deploy the plugin to the remote repository.

If that is not desired it should however work fine. You might be running into a problem with your Maven repository meta data. I would try to run

```
mvn -U com.tools:generate:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:generatepom
```

forcing an update as a next step.